# How to get metrics of Azure apim using an api

Tags: c#, azure, api, azure-api-management

I have to make a program on C# that get information about a few apis of Azure APIM, can I achieve this through an api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the workarounds you can try is to get the viewed diagnostic data from Azure Monitor which stores the metrics of API Management

For listing metrics for a resource

```
IEnumerable<Metric> metrics = await readOnlyClient.Metrics.ListAsync(resourceUri: resourceUri, cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);
```

or with a filter

```
// The comma-separated list of metric names must be present if a filter is used
var metricNames = "name.value eq 'CpuPercentage'"; // could be concatenated with " or name.value eq '<another name>'" ...

// Time grain is optional when metricNames is present
string timeGrain = " and timeGrain eq duration'PT5M'";

// Defaulting to 3 hours before the time of execution for these datetimes
string startDate = string.Format(" and startTime eq {0}", DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3).ToString("o"));
string endDate = string.Format(" and endTime eq {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("o"));

var odataFilterMetrics = new ODataQuery<Metric>(
    string.Format(
        "{0}{1}{2}{3}",
        metricNames,
        timeGrain,
        startDate,
        endDate));

Write("Call with filter parameter (i.e. $filter = {0})", odataFilterMetrics);
metrics = await readOnlyClient.Metrics.ListAsync(resourceUr
```

**REFERENCES :**

- [Monitor published APIs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor.md#tutorial-monitor-published-apis)
- [Retrieve Azure Monitor metrics with .NET](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/monitor-dotnet-metrics-api#retrieve-azure-monitor-metrics-with-net)